# Private online SVN repositories

Tags: svn, repository

I am planning to start a project with a team of 3-4 people and I was researching some online SVN repositories for a while to work when working as a team on the single project.

I'm hesitating to choose a free version to start with. I want a service that enables you to do the basic SVN stuff( Commit changes, update, merge, checkout) and maybe debug facilities.

I am trying to choose between [ProjectLocker](http://www.projectlocker.com/)  and [Origo](http://www.origo.ethz.ch/) but I will be glad if you point me to another similar SVN repository to work with for free. I would appreciate suggestions and recommendations based on experience! Thanks

Comment: Origo seems to have closed in May 2012, see answer by "geeky" in the following discussion: http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/304367-full

Comment: "everyone" just uses xp-dev.com.  they have the best service and prices.  for bigger companies/projects, Assembla is popular.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm currently using http://www.assembla.com. As well as SVN it has GIT and a number of other tools including ticketing. However I've only really used it for SVN, but for that it's pretty solid and I've never had any trouble with it. Works out at about $2/user/month for the private, https svn repositories. Public svn repositories are free.

Answer (score 3):

If you have your own hosted environment, I would strongly recommend [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/). To complement it from explorer, I would also recommend [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

Comment: I don't have my own hosted environment sadly!

Comment: However I am Happy with TortoiseSVN! Thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know another solution for you problem. However, I'm using dreamhost web hosting service which include free SVN repositories that you can configure whatever you want it.
I know it's not free (because you have to buy the hosting service first). Just throw in an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two further hosting-services for Subversion-repositories:

- [CloudForge](http://www.cloudforge.com/pricing)
- [Unfuddle](https://unfuddle.com)

However, I have never used these services.